# ClickOnce cross-browser

Tags: cross-browser, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce .NET 2 application that works perfectly on IE. However, my application does not work with any other browsers (the manifest gets downloaded as an xml file). I know that ClickOnce should only be supported on IE (and firefox when .net 3.5 is installed), but I was told that Google Chrome's installer (http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?hl=en&brand=CHMB&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-sk&utm_medium=ha&installdataindex=homepagepromo) is a ClickOnce bootstrapper and theirs works cross browser (firefox, opera and chrome - although I can guess how it works on chrome :)). Any ideas on how to achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 2):

This is browser-dependent. First, make sure your MIME types are defined correctly on the webserver where you are hosting your files.

Next, there is an add-in specifically for Firefox. (Google is your friend here.) We haven't had to use it very often, but try it and see if it helps you. Same for Chrome (they have their own add-in and I can't imagine that it would claim to work for other browsers). AFAIK, there's nothing available for Opera.